# ffmpeg - moov atom not found0/0

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to play a movie (`.mp4`) that i've encoded with `ffmpeg` and i get the following error:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fa39a802800] moov atom not found0/0
>   /movie.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Why does ffmpeg throw this error?

Thanks!

**Note:**
It's an `.exr` sequence that i've encoded, but i don't think it's a problem with my encoding settings since i've encoded another `.exr` sequence with the same settings and it worked.

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -y -loglevel info -threads 0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -framerate 60 -i /image.png -start_number 000000 -apply_trc bt709 -framerate 60 -i /sequence.%06d.exr -r 60 -preset medium -codec:v libx265 -ar 48000 -acodec aac -shortest -strict experimental -sn -vsync 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 31457280 -movflags +faststart  -x265-params high-tier=0:pmode=1:wpp=1:tune=fastdecode:bitrate=31457:fps=60:keyint=360:min-keyint=180:vbv-bufsize=31457:vbv-maxrate=31457:scenecut=0 
' -filter_complex "[2:v]crop=3440:2227:0:2560, scale=3440:768, rotate=0[input_num0];[1:v][input_num0]overlay=0:0[output_num0]" -map "[output_num0]:0" -map "0:0" output.mp4
```

**Console output:**

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'aevalsrc=0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f64le, 44100 Hz, mono, dbl, 2822 kb/s
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/image.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, monob(pc), 3840x1536, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
Input #2, image2, from '/sequence.%06d.exr':
  Duration: 00:00:32.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: exr, rgb48le(unknown/unknown/bt709), 5120x2560 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
[libx265 @ 0x7f9ee1003400] Unknown option: tune.
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.9
x265 [info]: build info [Mac OS X][clang 7.0.2][64 bit] 8bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x265 [warning]: Limit reference options 2 and 3 are not supported with pmode. Disabling limit reference
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 4 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 2 / wpp(24 rows)+pmode
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 180 / 360 / 0
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / 0 / 0
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-31457 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 31457 / 31457 / 0.900
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: lslices=8 deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to '/output.mp4':
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p, 3840x1536, q=2-31, 31457 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx265
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #2:0 (exr) -> crop (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx265)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_f64le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x7f9ee081f400] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
```

Comment: Run the encode again. If it doesn't work, show command and console output.

Comment: Done, i've edited my original post

Comment: Your EXRs are 5120x2560, but your crop is `3440:2227:0:2560`. Which does not make sense. No active image area is included. Also, why `rotate=0`? The image.png should be looped.

Comment: 3440x2227 is the size of the cropping region i want out of that 5120x2560 image, giving it a top left corner of (0,2560). I think it might be because i calculated the top left corner wrong? (since the (0,0) coordinate of ffmpeg is at the top left).
The rotation part is a parameter set by a python script, in that case it's 0 but it could be anything else.

Comment: I changed my `crop` filter arguments to `crop=3440:2227:0:0` and it still doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -threads 0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i /image.png -start_number 000000 -apply_trc bt709 -framerate 60 -thread_queue_size 512 -i /sequence.%06d.exr -filter_complex "[2:v]crop=3440:2227:0:0,scale=3440:768,rotate=0[input_num0];[1:v][input_num0]overlay=shortest=1,format=yuv420p[output_num0]" -preset medium -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -shortest -b:v 31457280 -x265-params high-tier=0:pmode=1:wpp=1:tune=fastdecode:bitrate=31457:fps=60:keyint=360:min-keyint=180:vbv-bufsize=31457:vbv-maxrate=31457:scenecut=0 -map "[output_num0]" -map 0:0 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

There are still some redundant settings, but those can be checked later on.

Comment: gives the same error

Comment: Switch to libx264 and see. And your console output looks incomplete. How many frames were encoded and muxed?

Comment: Still same error, all frames encoded..

Comment: Output to .ts or mkv

Comment: `mkv` works! why is that?
also, i get the error `Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)`, even though i set the size to 512..

Comment: So any chance you could please let me know why it happens? It's very weird.. never had a problem encoding .mp4's before